# mysql sorting bits

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Field "stars" in my table.

```
1 means **
2 means ***
4 means ****
```

now they can be combined like 3 means 2.5 and 6 means 3.5 stars. It an only be 2 values next to each other so something like 5 cant occur.
This works well with the output. The Problem now is the sorting. Right now i just sort by the field stars. Obviously this does not work correctly because the correct order would be like:

```
2.5stars, 3stars, 3.5stars
```

but those mean:

```
3,2,6
```

overall the correct sorting would be like:

```
1,3,2,6,4,12,8,24,16
```

I have a pagebrowser with limit and filters an everything so i dont want to select all rows and sort by hand. Is there a way to get this kind of sorting directly in my query?

Edit:

To be clear, this comes from Bitwise..

```
00001 = **
00010 = ***
00011 == 2.5*
00100 = ****
```

Comment: Why not just store it as an integer?  I fail to see why you'd even *want* to do something like this...?

Comment: Crazy idea, but why not just fix the source of the problem (the bizarre 1 = 2 stars, 2 = 3 starts, etc. set up) rather than use some obscure sorting "fix".

Comment: This comes from the cms, cant really change it

Comment: `1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2.5, 4 -> 4, 5 -> X, 6 -> 3.5` - I really don't get this system...

Comment: If you can, add a computed field or a trigger&field to the table that converts the rating to something sortable.

Comment: You could add a lookup table to provide a mapping to an ordering and then just join and order by the looked-up order column.

Comment: I dont like mappingtable this wouldn really be flexible, but the computed field is a good idea, gonna try that

Answer (score 2):

It's not pretty, but you can give this a shot.

```
SELECT x FROM y WHERE z
ORDER BY
CASE stars
    WHEN 1  THEN 1
    WHEN 3  THEN 2
    WHEN 2  THEN 3
    WHEN 6  THEN 4
    WHEN 4  THEN 5
    WHEN 12 THEN 6
    WHEN 8  THEN 7
    WHEN 24 THEN 8
    WHEN 16 THEN 9
    ELSE 10
END CASE
```

Comment: definitely not pretty, but I was about to suggest just this. Also check: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Comment: like the solution with the mapping table in a comment, this is neither nice nor flexible. If a User adds more elements in the Backend someone would have to add more lines here for sorting.

Comment: If this is a problem with a CMS though, then I would have thought flexibility wasn't an option.  If that's not the case, I'd be very tempted to suggest going with a straight integerial approach as the first commenter suggested.

Comment: The options are Flexible (the value) but it is always safed as an int built out of bits. Looked how to change that, but is not possible. However i used a computed field with cronjob which works just fine